# Why does initialization via inline function is not require to be done statically

Tags: c++, initialization

The code snippet below is from 3.6.2/3 N3797 C++14 final working draft:

```
inline double fd() { return 1.0; }
extern double d1;
double d2 = d1;  // unspecified:
                 // may be statically initialized to 0.0 or
                 // dynamically initialized to 0.0 if d1 is
                 // dynamically initialized, or 1.0 otherwise
                 // may be initialized statically or dynamically to 1.0
double d1 = fd();
```

As I understand that example, the initialization of both d1 and d2 is not required to be done statically. `double d2 = d1` is quite understandable (`d1` is not a `constant expression`). My question is the following:
Why does initialization via inline function is not required to be done statically?

Comment: because your function call is not a `constant expression` ?

Comment: @PlasmaHH But the function call postfix-expression substitutes during to function body during compile-time for inline function.

Comment: you are entirely misinterpreting what the `inline` keyword is for. It doesn't in any way force the compiler to inline something, it is for the purpose of inlining even ignore by most compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the function is marked as `inline` does not really change much in this case. The only real effect of the `inline` keyword is to tell the compiler / linker to accept that multiple definitions of that function might appear in the overall program (when linking all the object files together), which is needed when you define a function directly in a header file that may be included from several translation units (cpp files). It is a way to make an exception to the ODR (One Definition Rule) for functions that you would like to define in the headers, we call that an "inline definition" (or "inline function"), which is where the keyword gets its name. And if you look through the C++ standard, you will see that most mentions of the `inline` keyword are discussing issues related to providing inline definitions (i.e., implementing the function where it's declared, instead of in a separate cpp file).

Pretty much any function whose definition is available to the compiler can be a candidate for "function inlining" (which is not the same thing as "inline definition"). But this is purely an optimization choice that the compiler makes, and it is not a requirement. The only times that function inlining is mentioned in the C++ standard is to make it clear that if the compiler chooses to inline a function, it should not have any visible effect on the behavior of the code (they are all remarks like: "this should be true, even if the function is inlined"). The only relation between the `inline` keyword and "function inlining" is a suggestion, in the standard, that the keyword could also be considered as a hint that function inlining is desirable for that function (because it often is), but this is not a requirement, and I believe many compilers ignore it completely when it comes to deciding whether to inline a function or not (mostly, because compilers don't need that hint, they perfectly capable of making that choice on their own).

That said, the `d1` variable in your example is being initialized with a call to a function which is not a `constexpr` function, meaning that it cannot be required to be done statically. It is only if the function is marked with `constexpr` that the compiler must try to evaluate it statically, thus leading to a possible static initialization of a non-local variable from that call. Marking the function as `inline` makes no difference whatsoever in this context, because, except for the application of ODR, an inline function is required to behave (at least, ostensibly) the same as any other function.

Comment: Exhaustive answer. But could you get standard reference, described ODR exception for inline functions?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv The clause that describes the ODR exception for inline functions is 7.1.2/4 from the n3337 version (C++11). And for the rest of my comments, just make a word search for "inline" and you will find all the relevant comments in the standard related to that.